# EMV Wrong length when generating ARQC - CDOL1

Tags: apdu, emv

I’m generating successfully ARQC’s with VISA credit, debit and MC credit cards, but when i try to generate one with MC Debit i get "6700" command wich means "wrong length", here is my CDOL and my command:

The CDOL1 sum of all data objects length is expecting 35 bytes (Hex 23)

CDOL1
9f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f3403

COMMAND
80AE80002300000000000000000000000004848000008000048413021300550320312100001e0300

Does anybody have an idea what i’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not include 9F4C(ICC Dynamic Number) in your CDOL1. You must  include this tag its a must for calculation for ICC Dynamic Data in first Generate AC.